# Kibana create multiple charts using queries from list

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, kibana-4

I'm trying to create multiple charts in kibana using values from a list in a query.

For example assume I have a list of cities that sends messages between them (to one or more other cities):

```
cities: [Moscow London Paris Munich]
```

Each city is sending messages to other cities, those messages can get to their destination or get lost.

for each city I have data of which messages it sent and which of them got to the destination, e.g:

```
London sent:
date, destination, received
15.2, [Moscow Paris], [Paris]
14.2, [Moscow Paris Munich], [Paris Munich]
```

Now I want to create the following charts - While "investigating" a specific city, i want to display message delivery success rate.

For example, while investigating London, i want these charts

```
percentage of succesfull deliveries from London to Paris as function of date
percentage of succesfull deliveries from London to Moscow as function of date
```

and so on, same for each other city

The graphs I'm expecting to see are something like this:

[image]

I'm using Kibana 4.2, is it possible doing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible, if you also added the amount of unsuccessful deliveries to the chart. Your bucket would be Date Histogram, to Y axis you could add sum aggregations of succesful and unsuccesful deliveries, and from Options you could select precentage bar mode.

Addition: Charts wouldn't look just like ones you pictured, as they would always be of the same heigth but with precentages of successful/unsuccesful deliveries. Depending on your data, you might need to aggregate it a bit in Logstash to get the numeric values of the events.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my main problem here is how to use values from the list in the queries. I want the cities to be taken automatically from the list instead of manually making multiple charts and writing the query in each one.

Comment: Oh, now I see. In that case we'll both need to wait for someone more experienced to answer this.

Comment: in 2022 any new answer for that ?